# Find the power series expansion about $z=3$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Find the power series expansion for

$$f(z)=\frac{z^2}{4-z}$$

about the point $z=3$. So I know

$$\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$$

And we can write

$$\frac{z^2}{4-z}=\frac{z^2}{4-z}=\frac{1}{4}\frac{z^2}{1-\frac{z}{4}}.$$

So you just "push" in the $z^2$ and $1/4$ into the exponent portion of the sum and I know

$$\frac{1}{1-(z-3)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z-3)^n.$$

Somewhere I got a hint that

$$\frac{z^2}{4-z}=-z-4+\frac{16}{1-(z-3)}$$

But I dont see this at all. Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Long division.

Comment: In what region do you want the convergence of the series? $|z-3|<1$?

Answer (score 1):

$$4-z= 1-(z-3)\phantom{00000000000000000000}$$

$$\begin{aligned}\frac{z^2}{4-z}
&=\frac{z^2}{1-(z-3)}\\&=z^2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty(z-3)^k\\
&=[(z-3)^2+6(z-3)+9]\sum_{k=0}^\infty(z-3)^k\\
&=9+15(z-3)+16\sum_{k=2}^\infty(z-3)^k\end{aligned}$$

The series converges when $|z-3|<1.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\frac{z^2}{z-4}=z+4+\frac{16}{z-4}=7+(z-3)-16\frac1{1-(z-3)}\stackrel{\text{for}\;|z-3|<1}=\ldots$$

Comment: so is my answer just $-z-4+16\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z-3)^n$?

Comment: also, you did the incorrect problem.. lol

Comment: @anonymous Bah, just change signs.

Answer (score 0):

By long division,

$$\frac{z^2}{4-z}=-z-4+\frac{16}{1-(z-3)}.$$

Thus the power series is

$$-z-4+16\sum_{n=0}^\infty(z-3)^n.$$

Comment: You should write $-z-4=-7-(z-3)$ and combine it with the $0$th and $1$st term of the sum to obtain a proper power series about $3$.